# CSS - Fluid Horizontal List, 1 Static Item, Hide Items When Limited Space

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

I'd like to have a fluid horizontal list with a static "Browse All" on the right. If possible, I'd like this to be a single unordered list.

`Item One | Item Two | Item Three | Item Four | Item Five | Item Six | Browse All`

The only catch is, as the screen narrows, I'd like to hide the far right items when the space isn't there ( excluding the :last ).

`Item One    |    Item Two    |    Item Three    |    Item Four    |   Browse All`

Is there a way to accomplish this with CSS or do I need to get into some JavaScript? If I need to use JavaScript what's the best approach? Do I detect how many are visible and set the widths on each? I tried with CSS Media Queries but the variable character length of the list items make that difficult.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is showing part of an item acceptable? If so, this can be done with pure CSS. If not, you need JavaScript. Can jQuery be used?

Comment: It would not be acceptable. Yes, jQuery can be used as long as the fall back isn't too bad.

Comment: Can you use two elements for this? One that contains the items, seconds that contains the Browser All: <div>Item One | Item Two</div><div>Browse All</div>.

Comment: That was what I originally came up with then I just set a height with `overflow: hidden` on the menu. It creates some weird gaps I'm trying to avoid but I'm thinking it might be the best way if I go with straight CSS.

Comment: I don't even know how I'd go about detecting the items that aren't visible ( visible as in they are outside of the containers "view" area ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript+jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/37FtV/

```
//remove inline-block gaps
$('#menu').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#menu li').show();
    var checkWidth = 0;

    while (true) {
        checkWidth = 0;
        $('#menu li:visible').each(function() {
            checkWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
        });
        if ($(window).width() < checkWidth) {
            $('#menu li:not(:last-child):visible:last').hide();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}).resize();
```

Comment: Damn, well done. I really appreciate it. Way closer than what I had.

Answer (score 2):

Leaves a gap between the last item and Browser All, but uses no scripts at all.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body > div > div > span
        {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0px 4px;
            border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px; overflow: hidden;">
            <span>Item One</span>
            <span>Item Two</span>
            <span>Item Three</span> 
            <span>Item Four</span> 
            <span>Item Five</span> 
            <span>Item Six</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 4px;">Browse All</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great as well. I came up with this when I started but I just floated the "Browse All" to the right.

Comment: Yup, probably as close as you can get without JavaScript.

Comment: Not sure if you guys really care any more but I ended up with this. The only browser giving me trouble is IE7. - http://jsfiddle.net/p6nE5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<xmp>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
        #categories-container { max-width: 950px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; height:38px; overflow: hidden; background-color: #ccc; transition:all 300ms ease-in}
    #categories { list-style: none; padding: 0 90px 0 0; margin: 0 auto; height:auto; display:inline-block; }
    #categories li { float: left; background-color: #ddd; }
    #categories li.last { position: absolute; right: 0; }
    #categories li a { color: #222; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 10px; white-space: nowrap; }
    #categories li a:hover { background-color: #bbb; }
    li ul,li ul > li ul{display:none; position:absolute; list-style:none}
    li ul li{clear:both; list-style:none}
    li:hover ul{display: list-item}
  </style>      
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery("#browse").toggle(
    function(){         
        jQuery("#categories-container").height($("#categories").height());
    },
    function(){
        jQuery("#categories-container").height("38px");
    }   
    );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="categories-container">
    <ul id="categories">
      <li><a href="#">Anatomy Models</a>
      <ul>
        <li class=""><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Anatomy Models</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Anatomy Models</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Anatomy Models</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Anatomy Models</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Anatomy Models</a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" id="browse">Browse All</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/37FtV/11/

Comment: Could you please, at least add some information on what your answer add up to the accepted answer ? And have a valid html code ? (it is starting with a strange `<xmp>`)